# Close fancybox with outside click when overlay is set to null

Tags: jquery, click, overlay, fancybox-2

I am using the fancybox 2.1.4 plugin.
It works perfectly, but I have an issue.
I want to set the overlay to null and I want to close the fancybox when the user clicks outside(!) the fancybox container.

I have tried the following code, but it isn't working, since there's no overlay to click on.

```
   $(".fancy_gallery").fancybox.({
                loop:false, 
                padding:0, 
                helpers:{
                        overlay:null, 
                        closeClick:true
                        }
   });
```

So, how can I force fancybox to close, when I click outside of it?
Because, right now I must click on the close button to close it.

Comment: Maybe using the focusout handler

Comment: Have the same issue but can't solve this with the JFK answer :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could bind a `click` event to the fancybox parents (`html,body`) within the `afterShow` callback to force the closing (and `unbind` it after close) .... so try this code :

```
var fancyParent;
$(".fancy_gallery").fancybox({
    loop: false,
    padding: 0,
    helpers: {
        overlay: null
        // closeClick: true // useless without an overlay
    },
    afterShow: function () {
        fancyParent = $(".fancybox-wrap").parents(); // normally html and body
        fancyParent.on("click", function () {
            $.fancybox.close();
        });
        $(".fancybox-wrap").on("click", function (event) {
            // prevents closing when clicking inside the fancybox wrap
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    },
    afterClose: function () {
        fancyParent.unbind("click");
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QLmB9/)**

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you! Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but I'll be back when I've got enough points to do it. +1

Answer (score -1):

Your code must be like this:

```
helpers:  {
    title : {
        type : 'inside'
    },
    overlay : {
        showEarly : false
    }
}
```

These characters {-} are missing after the helpers name with a option inside.
FancyBox has a example here: http://jsfiddle.net/PFVxK/

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.

Comment: This don't answer the question and didn't help me that have the same issue with Fancybox.