# Fancybox: When click in any part of page open Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to implement a simple thing in my page using jQuery and [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/), but I can't put my code to work.

I need create a code that when user click in **any part of the page**, Fancybox opens a modal.

[image: If you don't know what's a modal, this is a modal.]

Currently, my code is the following:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(document).click(function(e){
            $.fancybox.open([{
              href: '/welcome',
              title: 'Welcome to Our Website!'
            }],
            {
              width: 800,
              height: 600
            });
          });
        });
</script>
```

For me the code is nice, but when I go to this page and click in a lot of parts of the page, nothing happens. Note: the console don't display any error messages, so, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you load Fancybox's JavaScript code first? And does the page /Welcome show something? The code you posted works fine, see the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pZvbT/

Comment: Yes, I loaded Fancybox first and /welcome is a existing path, it's working. One thing that I noted is: when I try to implement this in a button (to test and see if the problem is with Fancybox), anything happens and in "Network" tab of my Chrome console appears: "Name: welcome  |  Method: Get  | Status: (canceled) |  Type: pending" I think this give us a tip about the problem. You know what this error tell?

Comment: try `$("body").click()` instead of `document`. Also add `type:"iframe"` to your fancybox API options.

Comment: Hey JFK, I changed what I want in my project, and now I just open the Fancybox when I click on a Input or a img (and now's working). But don't go, I see you answered this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817046/close-fancybox-with-outside-click-when-overlay-is-set-to-null I tried to follow your answer but my Fancybox don't close when I click outside the modal, can you help me with this, please? :/

Comment: @FernandoPaladini : it doesn't work for you because now you have bound fancybox to the body (as per my comment.) I will post an answer here that solve both problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want fancybox to open when user clicks anywhere in your page after page load (and before they can interact with the page itself) then try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // add fancybox class to body on page load
    $("body").addClass("fancyopen");
    // bind click to body
    $(".fancyopen").on("click", function () {
        $.fancybox([{
            href: "/yourpage.html",
            title: "welcome to our website"
        }], {
            width: 300,
            height: 200,
            type: "iframe",
            afterShow: function () {
                $(".fancybox-wrap").on("click", function (event) {
                    event.stopPropagation(); // so you can click fancybox without calling it again
                });
            },
            afterClose: function () {
                $(".fancyopen").unbind("click").removeClass("fancyopen"); // now you can interact with the page
            }
        }); // fancybox
    }); // on
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/958nG/2/)**

Comment: @JFK when i do click on close symbol of popup at that time i want to set cookie.. what can i do?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13054/how-to-set-cookie-when-click-on-fancybox-close

Comment: get answer Thanks
  afterClose: function() {
  here code for cookie       
       }